# How do you trigger a keypress on a form field upon clicking anywhere other than that form field?

Tags: angularjs

I have a form field that upon clicking enter or pressing save the field saves.  What I'd like to have happen in addition to this is for field to save when the user clicks anywhere else on the page.

```
<input type="text" id="location" ng-model="location" ui-keypress="{enter: 'editLocation = !editLocation'}" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">

<a ng-click="editLocation = !editLocation" title="Click here or press the &quot;Enter&quot; key to save this edit.">
    <i class="icon-ok"> Save</i></a>
```

What'd be the best way to achieve this using AngularJS?

Answer (score 0):

Using the "onBlur" event from javascript ? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp

```
<input onBlur="myfunctionToSave()" ...>
```

Answer (score 0):

Enter ngBlur.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngBlur

```
<input ng-blur="saveStuffOnLeave()">
```